# Dual of the empty function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is $|Y^{\emptyset}|=1$ but $|\emptyset^Y|=0$ where $Y\neq \emptyset$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11771/why-is-y-emptyset-1-but-emptysety-0-where-y-neq-emptyset)

Let $Y^X$ denote the set of all functions (i.e. *relations*, or *ordered pairs*) having signature $X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary sets. Additionally, we should note that $Y^X$ is always a subset of $\wp({X \times Y})$.

It can be shown that $Y^{\varnothing}$ contains only one element, namely $\varnothing$ (the [empty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function)). I would expect that similarly , $\varnothing^X$ would yield the same [1]. According to [Halmos' book on Naive Set Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Set_Theory_(book)) this is not the case, and in fact, $\varnothing^X$ is empty—i.e. there exist no functions having signature $X \rightarrow \varnothing$.

**Question**: Given that $Y^\varnothing$ contains the empty function, why do we not see the existence of a concept dual to the *empty function* in $\varnothing^X$? Or am I just being pedantic in my reading [2] and missing the point entirely?

Essentially, I'm curious why we do not see a function having signature

$$X \rightarrow \varnothing$$

[1] Both $\wp(\varnothing \times Y)$ and $\wp(X \times \varnothing)$ result in $\{\varnothing\}$, leaving us with both sets of functions in question being a subset of $\{\varnothing\}$.

[2] A direct quote of what we're required to show:

> Exercise: (i) $Y^\varnothing$ has exactly one element, namely $\varnothing$, whether or not $Y$ is empty or not, and (ii) if $X$ is not empty, then $\varnothing^X$ is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\emptyset^{X} = \{\emptyset\}$ if $X=\emptyset$, and $\emptyset^X = \emptyset$ if $X\neq\emptyset$.

The reason that if $X\neq\emptyset$ then $\emptyset^X=\emptyset$ just comes down to the definition of "function". For $R\subseteq X\times\emptyset =\emptyset$ to be a function, for each $x\in X$ there must exist $y\in \emptyset$ such that $(x,y)\in R$ (and in addition, if $(x,y),(x,y')\in R$, then $y=y'$); this is impossible for any given $x\in X$, so no subset is a function. That is, there are no functions from a nonempty set to the empty set.

However, if the domain is empty, then the requirements for $R$ to be a function are vacuously satisfied, so the empty set is indeed a function $\emptyset\to\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In hindsight this was quite a silly question; I essentially ignored the contradiction that arose from the $\exists$ part of $\forall x \in X, \exists y \in Y$ s.t. $(x,y) \in f$

Answer (score 4):

For every set $X$ there is a unique function $\emptyset \to X$ defined as follows: .

If $X$ is non-empty, there is no corresponding function $X \to \emptyset$ because there are no elements of the range for the function to map an element of the domain to. This is not a problem in the other direction because $\emptyset$, by definition, has no elements.

If the lack of duality bothers you, it's because the correct dual notion is that for every set $X$ there is a unique function $X \to 1$ (where $1$ is a one-element set) sending every element of $X$ to the unique element of $1$. In category-theoretic terminology we say that $\emptyset$ is an [initial object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) in the category of sets, whereas $1$ is a terminal object. In general there's no reason to expect these two things to be the same. When they are (more precisely, when the unique map $\emptyset \to 1$ is an isomorphism) we say that the category has a zero object.